# linux yum through a socks v5 proxy

Tags: linux, firewall, proxy, yum

I can't use yum because port 80,443 are being blocked by a firewall.

I setup a ssh proxy tunnel (socks v5), it works fine.

I've tried to find how to use yum with a socks v5, but looks like it only can be done with a http proxy.

how can I use yum with a socks v5 proxy? I can't use http proxy.

EDIT: additional information

I can't use yum at all.
distros: fedora 16 and ubuntu, neither of these two have a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ProxyChains? http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't have installed proxychains. And I can't install it from source because I don't have a c compilter